# how to set QTableWidgetItem checkbox at the top of the cell in qtablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I have added checkbox randomly to every row of QTableWidget using following code

```
 self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()

 chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()

 chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | 
 QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

 chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

self.table.setItem(self.table.rowCount()-1,0,chkBoxItem)
```

But the checkbox always at center of the cell please let me know how to align checkbox at top of the cell.

Comment: You would probably need to create a 'container' widget, put the QCheckBox in that and control it's position in the widget using a QVBoxLayout or maybe a QSpacerItem. Then put the container widget in the table.

Comment: I can not use any container because I have to change lot of thing so please tell  solution accordingly